# How to use multiple values in case statement in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Consider the below

```
Declare @t table(Val int, name varchar(100))
Insert into @t select 1,'name1' 
union all select 1,'name2' 
union all select 2,'name3'
union all select 3,'name4'
```

If I want to get the records pertainig to Val 1 or 2 the choice is an IN clause. But we have some condition based on which the values needs to be choosen. Henceforth, we are going ahead with CASE approach as under

```
declare @type int  = 1
select *
from @t 
where val  = case when @type =1 then 1  end or
      val  = case when @type =1 then 2
             end
```

It works fine as **select * from @t where val in (1,2)**(we cannot use this as the value has to be determined at runtime and we are not using any dynamic query). Is there any other way to simulating the IN clause?

This is just for the sake of knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: your condition `@type =1` is same in both cases ?

Comment: Your example isn't very clear (to me, at least). Could you try expanding on what you're trying to do?

Comment: this is just an example. the type value will be passed at runtime. So if type  =2 then we need to pick up records for val =3

Comment: Actually we have implemented a simulated version of IN clause using case statement.Is there any other way using CASE only by which we can achieve the same.This is just for my sake of knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your code takes a single values as a parameter, but that the value relates to a list of values, you could just use a mapping table...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE pseudo_in_clause (@type INT)
AS

DECLARE @map TABLE (
  type  INT,
  val   INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (type, val)
)

INSERT INTO @map (type, val) VALUES (1, 1),
                                    (1, 2),
                                    (2, 3)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable      AS data
INNER JOIN
  @map           AS map
    ON data.val = map.val
WHERE
  map.type = @type
```

The map could be a permanent table, a temp table such as above,  function, etc.

Alternatively, you can still use an IN clause in the CASE statement...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable      AS data
WHERE
  CASE WHEN @type = 1 AND data.val IN (1,2) THEN 1
       WHEN @type = 2 AND data.val IN (3,4) THEN 1
                                            ELSE 0
  END = 1
```

Personally I prefer the `JOIN` version.

Comment: Or...  `WHERE @type = CASE WHEN data.val IN (1,2) THEN 1 WHEN data.val IN (3,4) THEN 2 END`

Answer (score 0):

Do you *have* to use `CASE`? This should work as well:

```
…
WHERE @type = 1 AND data.val IN (1, 2)
   OR @type = … AND data.val IN (…)
   OR …
```

Although I must say that I like [@Dems's suggestion about using a join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11151327/297408) best of all. Note that you could use an inline table instead of a table variable, thus making the entire thing a single query:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable AS data
  INNER JOIN (
    VALUES
      (1, 1),
      (1, 2),
      (2, 3)
  ) AS map ON data.val = map.val
WHERE map.type = @type
```